# Beautiful soup text returns blank

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website, but it returns blank, can you help please? what am i missing?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://ks.wjx.top/jq/50921280.aspx'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.text)
```

Comment: It is working fine for me, printing some javascript code. Try checking `page.status_code`, whether it is `200`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a response, add the [`User-Agent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header to `requests.get()`, otherwise, the website thinks that your a bot, and will block you.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://ks.wjx.top/jq/50921280.aspx"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"
}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```